# How can i get InputConnection in WebView?

Tags: android, webview

On my Web View project, i need to handle android soft Keyboard

If i do not extends Web View, How can i get Input Connection ?????

```
mBinding.wvMain.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
```

i want to use like this...

```
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    BaseInputConnection ic = new BaseInputConnection(this, true);
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER; // Tells the keyboard to show the number pad
    return ic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create your own class and inherit WebView

```
class CustomWebView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : WebView(context, attrs) {
override fun onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs: EditorInfo?): InputConnection {
    val ic = BaseInputConnection(this, true)
    outAttrs!!.inputType =
        InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
    return ic
}}
```

Step 2 : Use CustomWebView in your XML

```
<com.example.testapp.CustomWebView
        android:id="@+id/wvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:longClickable="false" />
```

Now in you Activity you can use you custom web view like.

```
mBinding.wvMain.loadUrl(url)
mBinding.wvMain.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```